# Error while serializing a class to XML

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, xml-serialization

I am serializing Linq object to using XmlSerializer but I am getting

> "There was an error reflecting type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1"

I have extended the Linq object with Serilizable attributes, something that m I doing incorrect here?

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Customer
{
}

[Serializable]
public partial class Comment
{
}


[Serializable]
public class CustomerArchive
{
    public Customer MyCustomer{ get; set; }
    public Comment MyComment { get; set; }
}



 internal static void Serialize(IEnumerable<CustomerArchive> archive, string fileName)
 {
      var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<CustomerArchive>)); // Error

      using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
      {
           using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
           using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw)
           {
                Indentation = 5,
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
           })
           serializer.Serialize(writer, new List<CustomerArchive>(archive));
       }
 }
```

Comment: on which line you are getting the error

Comment: var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<CustomerArchive>)); on this line ..:-(

Comment: what does the inner exception tell you? Keep following the inner exceptions until you get to the last one.

Comment: did you check inner exception?

Comment: Similar error {"There was an error reflecting type 'CustomerArchive'."} There was an error reflecting property 'MyCustomer'

Comment: @KeshavdasM Then why don't you post the Customer class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some properties inside `MyCustomer` class that cannot be serialized by the `XML Serializer`. Like a generic `Dictionary<>` for example.

Put `[XmlIgnore]` attribute on those properties and try again. If after that your code works you will simply need to make some surrogate properties that would serialize to XML and back without any issues.

Comment: Thank you, [NonSerialized] didn't worked but [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore] has done my job

Comment: Nice catch :) That's what I was going for.